# Chaining multiple async calls and data manipulation within promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Is there a better way to do this (clean, efficient, good practices)?

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk'

aws.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'))

ebs.describeApplications().promise()
  .then(({ Applications }) => Applications.map(app => { return { ...app, Environments: [] }}))
  .each(app => {
    return ebs.describeEnvironments({ ApplicationName: app.ApplicationName }).promise()
      .then(({ Environments }) => app.Environments = Environments)
      .catch(error => { throw error })
  })
  .then(applications => {
    console.log(applications)
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

It works but it feels wrong to me.

Here is a sample of a return from each calls:

describeApplications:

```
{
    "Applications": [
        {
            "ApplicationName": "test-application", 
            "Versions": [
                "Sample Application"
            ], 
            "DateCreated": "2017-02-05T03:39:41.144Z", 
            "ConfigurationTemplates": [], 
            "DateUpdated": "2017-02-05T03:39:41.144Z", 
            "ResourceLifecycleConfig": {
                "VersionLifecycleConfig": {
                    "MaxCountRule": {
                        "DeleteSourceFromS3": false, 
                        "Enabled": false, 
                        "MaxCount": 200
                    }, 
                    "MaxAgeRule": {
                        "DeleteSourceFromS3": false, 
                        "Enabled": false, 
                        "MaxAgeInDays": 180
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

describeEnvironments:

```
{
    "Environments": [
        {
            "ApplicationName": "test-application", 
            "EnvironmentName": "Sample-env", 
            "VersionLabel": "Sample Application", 
            "Status": "Ready", 
            "EnvironmentLinks": [], 
            "EnvironmentId": "********", 
            "EndpointURL": "********", 
            "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.5.0 running Docker 1.12.6", 
            "CNAME": "********", 
            "Health": "Green", 
            "AbortableOperationInProgress": false, 
            "Tier": {
                "Version": " ", 
                "Type": "Standard", 
                "Name": "WebServer"
            }, 
            "HealthStatus": "Ok", 
            "DateUpdated": "2017-02-05T03:46:17.325Z", 
            "DateCreated": "2017-02-05T03:39:46.072Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the results of my code:

```
[{
    ApplicationName: 'test-application',
    DateCreated: 2017 - 02 - 05 T03: 39: 41.144 Z,
    DateUpdated: 2017 - 02 - 05 T03: 39: 41.144 Z,
    Versions: ['Sample Application'],
    ConfigurationTemplates: [],
    ResourceLifecycleConfig: {
        VersionLifecycleConfig: {
            MaxCountRule: {
                Enabled: false,
                MaxCount: 200,
                DeleteSourceFromS3: false
            },
            MaxAgeRule: {
                Enabled: false,
                MaxAgeInDays: 180,
                DeleteSourceFromS3: false
            }
        }
    },
    Environments: [{
        EnvironmentName: 'Sample-env',
        EnvironmentId: '********',
        ApplicationName: 'test-application',
        VersionLabel: 'Sample Application',
        SolutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.5.0 running Docker 1.12.6',
        EndpointURL: '********',
        CNAME: '********',
        DateCreated: 2017 - 02 - 05 T03: 39: 46.072 Z,
        DateUpdated: 2017 - 02 - 05 T03: 46: 17.325 Z,
        Status: 'Ready',
        AbortableOperationInProgress: false,
        Health: 'Green',
        HealthStatus: 'Ok',
        Tier: {
            Name: 'WebServer',
            Type: 'Standard',
            Version: ''
        },
        EnvironmentLinks: []
    }]
}]
```